# combinatorial design problem

Tags: combinatorial-designs

A combinatorial design has six varieties {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, and nine blocks of size 2. Every variety occurs in three blocks, and the design is simple. Prove that there are exactly two non-isomorphic ways to do this.

I was able to solve a similar problem which asked me to construct two non-isomorphic designs with three varieties and five blocks of size 2, and  every possible pair of varieties occurring at least once.

How can I develop this one to solve the first quesion?

Answer (score 2):

Notice that you are counting isomorphism classes of simple graphs on six vertices in which every vertex has degree three.

If there is a triangle in the graph, then one easily sees that the whole graph is

[image]

Indeed, no two triangles can share an edge, so that is the only possibility.

If there is no triangle, let $x$ be a vertex and let $a$, $b$, $c$ be its neighbors. No two of $a$, $b$, $c$ can be connected, because that would create a triangle. It follows that all three of them are connected to the other two vertices $u$ and $v$. That completely determines the graph, which is then

[image]

Comment: So the correspondence between graphs and designs is:

vertices - varieties;
edges - blocks;
degree - frequencies;
are neighbors - are in the same block?

Comment: Also, can you explain this further?: "Indeed, no two triangles can share an edge"

Comment: just check that if two triangles share an edge, you cannot connect the remaining two vertices with the correct degrees.